# pandas auto append index number at front of each line in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Sorry i am still new to panda module and still learning python as well. I am trying to extract a row data by filtering a specific subscription from a cell and output to a text file and it work, but i found out each line has a random digit of index with a comma, is there something i need to add to remove the index number? Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

path = '/Users/myname/Downloads/azure_ip_addresses.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df = df[(df['Subscription Name'] == "subscription1") | (df['Subscription Name'] ==  "subscription2") | (df['Subscription Name'] ==  "subscription3") | (df['Subscription Name'] ==  "subscription4") | (df['Subscription Name'] ==  "subscription5") | (df['Subscription Name'] ==  "subscription6")]
df = df[["IP Address"]]
df.to_csv("/Users/nleong02/Downloads/result.txt")
```

The output look like this:

```
,IP Address
26,10.1.1.1
43,10.1.1.2
48,10.1.1.3
```

I tried using re.sub() or rsplit() but doesn't help much. If i can fix the indexing, i can just the rsplit("\n") again.

Comment: In "to_csv" call add argument "index=False".

Comment: well damn, you just saved my day! it works like charm, but i still seeing a double quote on some line:

10.1.1.1
""
10.1.1.2

,can rstrip() or any function able to remove it?

Comment: This may mean there is a quote `"` in the original data. You can e. g. try ` df["IP Address"] =  df["IP Address"].str.replace('"', '')` to remove these before writing the dataframe to a CSV.